# Check if boost::multiindex container is comparable

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

In my function I want to check if calss is comparable and perform comparison only if it is:

```cpp
template <typename T>
int compare(const T& a, const T& b)
{
    if constexpr (std::three_way_comparable<T>) {
        std::cerr << "comparable " << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
        if (a == b) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (a < b) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a > b) {
            return 1;
        }
    } else {        
        std::cerr << "not comparable " << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine for simple cases such as:

```cpp
struct CompStruct
{
    int         a {};
    std::string b;
    auto        operator<=>(const CompStruct&) const = default;
};

struct UncompStruct
{
    int         a {};
    std::string b;
    auto        operator<=>(const UncompStruct&) const = delete;
};

    CompStruct cs_a, cs_b;
    compare(cs_a, cs_b); // prints "comparable""

    UncompStruct ucs_a, ucs_b;
    compare(ucs_a, ucs_b); // prints "not comparable"
```

But fail to compile when using nested boost::multiindex with something uncomaprable inside:

```cpp
namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
using MultiIndex = bmi::multi_index_container<
    UncompStruct, bmi::indexed_by<bmi::random_access<>>>;
    
struct bad_type : std::map<std::string, MultiIndex>
{};

bad_type bt_a;
bad_type bt_b;
compare(bt_a, bt_b);  // fails to compile
```

If I change `UncompStruct` inside multiindex to `CompStruct` it compiles fine.

**Full code here:** https://godbolt.org/z/s5f4E63hc

**Question:** Is there suggestion on how to check if class is *really* comparable.

Comment: Unless all container types implements `SFINAE` correctly for the comparison operators, then there is really nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Looks like a libstdc++ bug to me. Compiles and runs fine with libc++.

Comment: Yup std::map's `operator<=>` doesn't seem to be SFINAE friendly in libstdc++ @n.m.willseey'allonReddit. It might be a standard defect though

Comment: It also fails on msvc.